# More graceful way to do bulk update in EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6, crud

This is in a WPF application.

Currently I have the following code which works, but is slow:

```
        public void IgnoreOffers(ICollection<Offer> offers)
        {
            using (var context = new DbContext())
            {

                foreach (Offer o in offers)
                {
                    var offer = context.Offers.Find(o.Id);
                    offer.Ignore = true;
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

I know all the offers exist already in the database

Is there a more performant way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

This library allows you to perform `BatchUpdate`

```
context.Offers.Where(o => offers.Contains(o.Id)
        .BatchUpdate(o => new Offer() { Ignore = true });
```

If you have too many offers, you might need to do it in multiple batch as the number of parameter in SQL is limited.

Everything will be done on the database side, so no offer will be needed to be loaded on the application side.

This method will offer you the best performance.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](https://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is not free but offers the `BulkUpdate` features.

```
// BulkUpdate
context.BulkUpdate(offers);

// If you want to only update the `Ignore` property
context.BulkUpdate(offers, o => o.ColumnInputExpression = x => new { x.Ignore });
```